# Resolved ["Method ResponseFactory::toArray does not exist."]

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel 7.6 and Vue 2.

I am try to convert Laravel collection to array.
This is orginal code which works.

```
  public function index()
{
    $books = Book::all()->toArray();
    return array_reverse($books);
}
```

- I need to get this to covert to array because it easier to handle with vue.
- First I pass profile_id to find all educations for it
- then I try to convert it to array for vue.

  ````
  public function index($id)
  { 
  if ($education = Education::where('profile_id',  
  $id)->get()) {
  }
  return response()->toArray($education); ```
  ````

I am getting error message: "Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::toArray does not exist."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are calling `toArray()`on the response, while you should call it on the `$education` collection.

Try with:
`return response()->json($education->toArray());`

This will generate a full JSON response with the $education array